# VLC Media Player Desktop Streaming Optimization

Tags: linux, video, android, vlc-media-player, streaming

I need to stream my **Desktop** over **HTTP** using VLC Media Player.

My requirement is to achieve the streaming delay ***less than 1s***. 
Now I am achieving delay of about 3-5 seconds.

What Options(configurations) such as **frame-rate** , **Trans-coding Profile**(`Encapsulation`,`Video codec`,...)  should I alter  in-order to get the **desired speed.**

For Now I am testing with Linux Desktop Client but on **Production Android** will be the **client over HTTP**. Hence Considering android client for optimization will be appreciated.

My Streaming Machine is Ubuntu Linux 14.04 , 4GB RAM,Intel® Core™ i3-2328M CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4.

```
VLC Media Player Version 2.1.6
```

Comment: HTTP and the latency you are seeking is unlikely to achieve. Especially if the sender and receiver are not on the same network, but connect over the Internet. A major issue will be client side buffering, unless you have full control over the client side. What is your use case anyway?